# How to find parent element based on its child element using XPath

Tags: android, xpath, android-uiautomator, appium-android

I'm creating a function to return the given element's XPath. To do it, I need to find a way to get the parent element of a given child element.

I'm wondering if there's a way to do it like this:

```
AndroidElement parentElement = childElement.findElement(By.xpath("SOME_XPATH_value"));
```

The idea is to get the parent element based on the known child element.

It's working fine when working with WebElement, but with AndroidElement, it's not working.

**EDIT**
Here's the XML of the page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<hierarchy index="0" class="hierarchy" rotation="0" width="1080" height="1812">
  <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1812]" displayed="true">
    <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][1080,1812]" displayed="true">
      <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,72][1080,1065]" displayed="true">
        <android.view.ViewGroup index="0" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.view.ViewGroup" text="" resource-id="io.testproject.demo:id/decor_content_parent" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,72][1080,1065]" displayed="true">
          <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" resource-id="io.testproject.demo:id/action_bar_container" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,72][1080,240]" displayed="true">
            <android.view.ViewGroup index="0" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.view.ViewGroup" text="" resource-id="io.testproject.demo:id/action_bar" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,72][1080,240]" displayed="true">
              <android.widget.TextView index="0" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.TextView" text="TestProject Demo" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[48,115][526,196]" displayed="true" />
            </android.view.ViewGroup>
          </android.widget.FrameLayout>
          <android.widget.FrameLayout index="1" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" resource-id="android:id/content" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,240][1080,1065]" displayed="true">
            <android.view.ViewGroup index="0" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.view.ViewGroup" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,240][1080,1065]" displayed="true">
              <android.widget.ScrollView index="0" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.ScrollView" text="" resource-id="io.testproject.demo:id/scrollView" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[24,240][1056,874]" displayed="true">
                <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" resource-id="io.testproject.demo:id/name_components" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[24,240][1056,874]" displayed="true">
                  <android.widget.TextView index="0" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.TextView" text="Full Name" resource-id="io.testproject.demo:id/labelFullName" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[24,240][1056,297]" displayed="true" />
                  <android.widget.EditText index="1" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.EditText" text="Enter your Full Name" resource-id="io.testproject.demo:id/name" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="true" long-clickable="true" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[24,297][1056,433]" displayed="true" />
                  <android.widget.TextView index="2" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.TextView" text="Password" resource-id="io.testproject.demo:id/labelPassword" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[24,433][1056,490]" displayed="true" />
                  <android.widget.EditText index="3" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.EditText" text="Enter your password" resource-id="io.testproject.demo:id/password" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="true" password="true" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[24,490][1056,628]" displayed="true" />
                  <android.widget.TextView index="4" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.TextView" text="Hint: password is 12345" resource-id="io.testproject.demo:id/labelPasswordHint" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[24,628][1056,685]" displayed="true" />
                  <android.widget.Button index="5" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.Button" text="LOGIN" resource-id="io.testproject.demo:id/login" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[24,730][1056,874]" displayed="true" />
                </android.widget.LinearLayout>
              </android.widget.ScrollView>
            </android.view.ViewGroup>
          </android.widget.FrameLayout>
        </android.view.ViewGroup>
      </android.widget.FrameLayout>
    </android.widget.LinearLayout>
  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
</hierarchy>
```

So, for example, I want to get the parent element of:

```
<android.widget.TextView index="0" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.TextView" text="Full Name" resource-id="io.testproject.demo:id/labelFullName" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[24,240][1056,297]" displayed="true" />
```

Which supposed to be:

```
<android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="io.testproject.demo" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" resource-id="io.testproject.demo:id/name_components" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[24,240][1056,874]" displayed="true">
```

Comment: Can you post the html/xml?

Comment: Hi @JackFleeting, I've added the XML of my page to the original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following as your xpath expression and see if it works:

```
//hierarchy//*[local-name()='android.widget.TextView'][@resource-id="io.testproject.demo:id/labelFullName"]/parent::*
```

or just

```
//hierarchy//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id="io.testproject.demo:id/labelFullName"]/parent::*
```

Comment: I'm trying to find a more generic solution. My purpose is to create a method that will return the XPath of a given element. One of the arguments of this method is the element itself (WebElement) and I'm trying to find a way to get its parent based on it. For example childElement.findElement(By.xpath("..")); I'm trying to find a way to make it work for Android.. For web it is working fine